# why does mongodb fail inconsistently with rails3 and rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

We have a rails 3, mongodb app using rspec, very normal setup I think in spec_helper:

```
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

But for some reason mongo seems to just fail at weird times in the tests inconsistently.  That is, 50% of the time the spec will run and no failures.  But 50% of the time a simple query to mongo will return a nil object and cause the spec to fail.  Any idea where to start debugging?  This never happens in development mode with a browser using the app, mongo is rock solid there.  Could it be the test env?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
Databasecleaner.orm = "mongoid"

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without DatabaseCleaner with:

```
config.before :each do
  Mongoid.master.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/ }.each(&:drop)
end
```